# How to integrate outlook calendar API and fetch the events from outlook calendar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar, outlook-api

I want to integrate outlook calendar API and fetch the events from outlook calendar and add them into my flutter app but I can't find any proper guide to do this so my question is how I can integrate outlook calendar API in my flutter app.

Comment: You can try to use [retrofit](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit) or [chopper](https://pub.dev/packages/chopper) to communicate with Outlook Calendar API(as with any other API). Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

First, you add o auth2 Client pub package

https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2_client

```
class Something{

    Future fetchOutlookCalender(
      {BlockCreateCustomTaskBucket provider}) async {

    var client = OAuth2Client(
        authorizeUrl:
            'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
        tokenUrl: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        redirectUri: 'com.example.upticker://oauth2redirect',
        customUriScheme: 'com.example.upticker');

    var token = await client.getTokenWithAuthCodeFlow(
        clientId: '32502b36-55b3-44b7-88ab-cf8d0ce273dc',
        scopes: ['openid profile offline_access user.read calendars.read']);
     print('accesstoken: '${token.accessToken}',')
}
```

Comment: <activity 
    android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity" >
 <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="com.example.upticker" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>

Comment: its shows error

Invalid argument (callbackUrlScheme): must be a valid URL scheme: "com.test.app"